# Importing contacts and mails from Gmail to business Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have created a business Gmail account from Google Apps with custom domain. I want to transfer my emails and contacts from my old Gmail to this one. The thing is, in Gmail settings there is a tab called "Accounts and import," while in my new business account there is "Accounts" there is import functionality I guess. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always export your Contacts to a Google CSV file and import that file to your new Contacts. Just hit `Gmail` in the upper left corner and select Contacts and find the Export option.

I see that the normal Gmail Import functionality is not available for Apps. You can always add your old Gmail as a POP address and import the mail that way. [Here](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13273) you can enable POP in your old inbox. And [here](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287) you find the configuration you have to enter in your Apps account.